# Mocking relative-path class instantiation with full-path mocker in pytest - impossible?

Tags: python, mockito, pytest, python-mock

I have 2 modules. The first one say `A`:

Inside module `A` I have:

```
from my_lib import SomeClass

def my_function:
    my_var = SomeClass()
    do something with my_var...
```

The package `my_lib` is a package I created and i pip-installed it locally into my site-packages (by running `pip install .` in the root directory of my package. I have `__init__.py` `__main__.py` and all the needed files for a correct package)

The other module is say `test_A`. Inside `test_A` I use mock pytest in the following way:

```
import A    
import pytest

def test_my_function(mocker):
    mocker.patch(target='my_lib.SomeClass', return_value='some_mock_value')
    A.my_function()
```

The problem is that mocking with `my_lib.SomeClass` **doesn't** apply the mock to the direct invocation of `SomeClass` within module `A` when the tests enter `my_function` within that module (a real SomeClass instance is returned). The only way it does work is when in module A i use SomeClass invocation like this:

```
import my_lib
.....
.....
my_var = my_lib.SomeClass()
```

That means I have to change the real module just so that the mock test will be able to mock the invoked class, which sounds wrong.

Patching **without** the full path like this:

`mocker.patch(target='SomeClass', return_value='some_mock_value')`

**will NOT work** since mock-pytest will not be able to import SomeClass (since `SomeClass` does not exist in site-packages, only `my_lib.SomeClass` does).

Is there an elegant solution to this situation ?

How to tell mock-pytest that `SomeClass` that is invoked in module `A` and `my_lib.SomeClass` from the mock path **relate to the same library** in site-packages ?

I've run out of ideas. Help ?

Comment: Patch `A.SomeClass`?

Comment: No, because module A has no attribute (=function) SomeClass. SomeClass exists only in my_lib which is imported from site-packages

Comment: No? Run e.g. `python -c "import A; print(A.SomeClass)" ` in a terminal, what do you get? What do you think happens with `A`'s local scope when executing the line `from my_lib import SomeClass` in `A.py`?

Comment: @hoefling Just tried it - it doesn't work and I get AttributeError from pytest-mock since before mocking it first tries to import the path A.SomeClass as if there is a package named A in site-packages (and there isn't) with SomeClass in it. I know it sounds strange but that's how mock expects its patch target to be - a full path to a VALID package/class that CAN be imported in a regular way.

The mock is not that smart as to understand that the inner scope of A will change and will contain SomeClass, mock is a very primitive and simple library.

Comment: Here's a [REPL with your code](https://repl.it/@hoefling/so-57148407) with an example of patching `ArgumentParser` class in `A.py` and **it's working**. _I know it sounds strange but that's how mock expects its patch target to be_ - no, that's wrong. I suggest to read [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) and [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) to fill the gaps.